# Is one permitted to wear a sheitel made from the hair of a human corpse?

Tags: halacha, hair, hair-covering, hanaah-benefit

Larger question: Is one allowed to derive benefit from a dead body?

**A couple of qualifiers:**

- obviously if there would be *zilzul* to the dead body in any form of course the answer would be no
- medical students operating on a cadaver doesn't seem to really be "*hana'ah*" so doesn't seem like a strong proof

The example that came to mind would be a *sheitel*.
Would one be allowed to wear a **sheitel** that was taken from the hair of a human corpse?

Comment: For all I know, hair may be more lenient than, say, flesh.

Comment: Better yet what about a Shetel that was worn by a corpse?

Comment: Hair is also interesting because it doesn't seem to be alive, but not sure if that *metzius* would have an impact *l'halacha* tho (based off a google search: "is hair dead")

Comment: Look back at the siman n sif u quoted. The rama clearly states that a wig would be fine to use. @DoubleAA

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is forbidden to derive benefit from a corpse, including its hair, even if the deceased commanded before dying that certain parts be given away for use. (Shulchan Aruch [YD 349:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.349.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))

Comment: it should be noted that the Rambam disagrees regarding hair ,Avel 14:21

Answer (score 1):

Yes.
   (ודוקא כשהם קשורים בשערות גופן אבל אינן קשורים מותר (כך משמע מפרש"י פ"ק דערכין) .Only when not fastened at all, i.e., it (the wig) hangs on a peg or hook, is it permitted. See Rama - S"A 349:2

Comment: האשה שנהרגה נהנין בשערה, ואמאי, איסורי הנאה נינהו... אמר רב בפאה נכרית... (ערכין ז ב)